# c++: owlnext + vcl: New Window missing its Parent

Tags: c++, window, vcl, owlnext

I have a Application mostly written with the owl-libary.

There I want open new vcl-windows out of the main owl-window.
This works great, though if a dialog-window is opened (even with `ShowModal`) and I focus another application, then the main-window get's into foreground but is blocked by the window behind it.

I guess the Problem is the missing parent-setting.

However, I can't convert owl's `TWindow` to vcl's `TWinControl`.

Is there a trick to set a vcl's `parent` setting to a owl's `TWindow`-Object?
Or could this be caused by something entirely different?

EDIT:
I'm using...

```
void(TWindow* parent){
    Form=new TForm((HWND)parent->Handle);
    Form->ParentWindow=parent->Handle;
    Form->BorderIcons >> biMinimize >> biMaximize << biSystemMenu; //No minimize, no maximize, but close
    Form->BorderStyle = bsSingle;
    Form->Position = poMainFormCenter;
    ...
    Form->ShowModal();
```

...now.
However, the new window is locked up and can not be clicked/closed/switched to.
Is there something I missed in using ParentWindow?

EDIT2:
I think it might be a Problem that the parent is a `TDecoratedMDIFrame`, which is a MDI-Container, so my dialog is treated like a mdi-child instead of a normal dialog...

Comment: Please be sure to read the tag wiki descriptions.  This question was tagged with [tag:owl], but it's not about OWL, the Web Ontology Language.  I've removed the tag.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: OWL (Object Window Library) is the predecessor to VCL, and has been carried on as an [open-source project](http://owlnext.sourceforge.net). Probably needs a new tag created for it.

Comment: Yes, I've seen some questions about it before.  It's just that [tag:owl] is for something else.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor ah, sorry, I missed owl's description as it seems the only available tag for object window library...

Comment: @Julian You can "create" tags by just writing them in (you might need a certain amount of rep before you can do that, though;  I'm not sure).  At any rate, I've created an [tag:owlnext] tag and added it to this question, as well as a few other questions.  Just a note, I noticed that some of your other questions that use OWLNext didn't have the [tag:c++] tag.  You'll tend to get many more views if you use a "mainline" language tag in addition to the more specific ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TWinControl` has a `ParentWindow` property for specifying a non-VCL parent window.

Also, in modern VCL versions, you can specify a `ParentWnd` when displaying a VCL dialog.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It was exactly what I was looking for, but I seem to be too dull to use it right^^ I added an EDIT at my question above: The new vcl-Form is locked up and not responding